# Angular-modal-service does not show modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Trying to set up a (I think) relatively simple modal to show the sites cookie policy.

The policy is on `/cookiepolicy`. Checked and that link works nicely.

I then created a button (that does call the code)

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href ng-click="showCookie()">Read More</a>
```

As I just want to call the modal for the url, nothing more is added to the html.

The function that calls the modal (which also is called and reports success as per the last line.)

```
app.controller('IndexController', function($scope, ModalService) {
    $scope.showCookie = function (data) {
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: "/cookie-policy",
            controller: "ModalController"
        }).then(function (modal) {

            //it's a bootstrap element, use 'modal' to show it
            modal.element.modal;
            modal.close.then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The modal also have its own controller

```
betchaHttp.controller('ModalController', function($scope, close) {

    // when you need to close the modal, call close
    close("Success!");
});
```

The thing is that when I press it, nothing comes up on the page, neither is there a error message. Am I missing something rather obvious (or not so obvious)

Comment: I guess it should be `modal.element.modal();`.

Comment: @akhurad I answered with the exact suggestion a bit ago

Comment: @scniro I forgot to refresh the page. Couldn't read your answer.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? Was my answer able to help you?

Comment: Sorry, missed answering and giving credit to you. Yes, your answer was spot on, just me missing the brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, this is just a small syntax typo on your end. Observe your `.then()` block and change...

```
modal.element.modal;     // -- nothing
```

to

```
modal.element.modal();  // -- fn call
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qb1fvmbm/) - demo